# How to search for string concatenation in java code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, string-concatenation

Is there a way to search for code which does String concatenation?

As suggested in this [article](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/02/05/top-10-easy-performance-optimisations-in-java/), it is performance-friendly if we use StringBuilder over String concatenation.

I would like to do a project-wide search for places where String concatenation is performed.

Comment: Is is complicated, because there are many ways to concat strings

Comment: The easiest way is to use a profiler - like Netbeans or visualvm - to identify the places where this is actually a _problem_ and then fix that.

Comment: @AndyTurner You are right.  Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do this.

By Default, the compiler converts your `String str = a + b;` kind of code to use StringBuilder.

Quoting the Docs:

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings. String concatenation is implemented through the
>   StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method. String
>   conversions are implemented through the method toString, defined by
>   Object and inherited by all classes in Java. For additional
>   information on string concatenation and conversion, see Gosling, Joy,
>   and Steele, The Java Language Specification.